# Made mistake editing, How can return back?

Tags: gedit

I opened a document and after editing it extensively I pressed the Save button (in gedit) by mistake. I was meaning to keep the original version and save the new one under another name. Is there any way I can recover my older file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you didn't change the preferences for gedit from the default you most likely have the original version still available.

Click on *open*, select *Other Documents* at the bottom. In the files window you will find a file with the same name that you used, but a `~` (Tilde) appended to the name. (If you saved *veryImportant.txt* you will additionally see *veryImportant.txt~*).

In case you don't see any files with a tilde at the end you must enable the diplay of "hidden files" by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>.

Now open that file and immedialtely save it under another name.